# I can't seem to initialize my first flutter project due to unknown error

Tags: android, flutter

When I run flutter doctor -v, everything checks out and no issues were found. However, once I create a new project, an error always pops up.

> flutter failed to copy c:\users\asdf\documents\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\templates\app\android.tmpl\app\src\main\res\mipmap-hdpi\ic_launcher.png to c:\users\asdf\desktop%E2%A0%80\project\untitled\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-hdpi\ic_launcher.png due to unknown error.
> The flutter tool cannot access the file or directory.
> Please ensure that the sdk and/or project is installed in a location that has read/write permissions for the current user.

As you can see, both the project file and the flutter installation files are both in a location that can be accessed without special permission. It does indeed still create a file but its missing a lot of the components necessary such as the lib folder that contains the main, the yamc, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should reinstall the flutter plugin and then reset the sdk location

Comment: how do i reset the sdk location?

Comment: Hi! Please add more descriptive instruction with cli commands or steps to perform this actions.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of Problem occurs mostly due to improper installation of flutter. Please totally reinstall flutter and errors will be gone.
Also, make sure to install all flutter necessary files in a directory which with read/write permissions.

Comment: what wkuld be a directory with both read and write permission? desktop?

Comment: Mostly you'll have read/write permission on your non-OS drive partition if you didn't mess up with the security of the drive in the past.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry I am late but hopefully it's still useful. I just got the same problem as you. And the problem exist because I have my antivirus turned on. It somehow blocked flutter from creating a new project. When I stopped my antivirus for a while, flutter could create the project normally